# Changing condition in a loop

Tags: matlab

I want to copy files from one place to another but only copy the files that have folder created, so the source contain folder i.e 'aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc' and destination folder contain 'bbb' 'ccc' so i would only copy the files from 'bbb' and 'ccc'

```
for i = 3:name_size
    MainIMAGE_Path = strcat(file_Paths_main, '\',result(i),'\images');
    IMAGE_Path = strcat(file_Paths_images,'\',file_names_images(i).name);
    IMAGE_dir = dir(fullfile(IMAGE_Path));
    IMAGE_Path = strcat(file_Paths_images,'\',file_names_images(i).name,'\',IMAGE_dir(3).name,'\12*');
    copyfile(IMAGE_Path, MainIMAGE_Path{1},'f');
    else

    end
end
```

but I don't know how to continue to write the code to make it work like that, currently it will try to copy the files to the folder that don't exist in the destination folder which giving error

```
Error using copyfile
No matching files were found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) function.

```
if exist(folder, 'dir') == 1
   copy_file();
end
```